# Flattening a Table in prep for Json

Tags: mysql, sql, json

Maybe it's that I'm tired but this is escaping me.

Let's say that I want to flatten this table:

```
a_id   a_val  b_id   b_val  c_id   c_val  d_id   d_val
1      a      10     b      100    c      1000   f   
1      a      20     d      200    g      null   null 
2      e      30     h      300    i      null   null   
2      j      40     k      null   null   null   null 
3      l      null   null   null   null   null   null
```

Into this query result:

```
id mystring 
1, (1:a,10:b,100:c,1000:f),(1:a,20:d,200:g) 
2, (2:e,30:h,300:i),(2:j,40:k) 
3, (3:l)
```

The table only renders four levels deep (a, b, c, d) so no dynamic sql issue.

Now I'd usually just use GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(...)) but that won't work with the Nulls present.  And maybe using coalesce somehow will solve this but... I feel pretty stupid at the moment... and I can't figure it out.

Unfortunately I can't use mysql json services on this installation so I need to construct the data. thanks.

Comment: I think you can nest the coalesces in the concats so that the concat is always rendering a value instead of null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here will probably just be a combination of clever concatenation and `IFNULL` calls. My shot in the dark:

```
SELECT a_id, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('(',
    a_id, ':', a_value, ',', 
    IFNULL(b_id, ''), IF(b_id IS NOT NULL, ':', ''), IFNULL(b_val, ''),
    ...repeat for c and d
   ')'
) SEPARATOR ',')
FROM table
GROUP BY a_id;
```

Comment: Yep.  That will do it nicely.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
select a_id as id,
group_concat(concat(
case isnull(a_id) when true then '' else '(' end,
coalesce(a_id, ''),
case isnull(a_id) when true then '' else ':' end,
coalesce(a_val, ''),
case isnull(b_id) when true then '' else ',' end,
coalesce(b_id, ''),
case isnull(b_id) when true then '' else ':' end,
coalesce(b_val, ''),
case isnull(c_id) when true then '' else ',' end,
coalesce(c_id, ''),
case isnull(c_id) when true then '' else ':' end,
coalesce(c_val, ''),
case isnull(d_id) when true then '' else ',' end,
coalesce(d_id, ''),
case isnull(d_id) when true then '' else ':' end,
coalesce(d_val,''),
case isnull(a_id) when true then '' else ')' end
) separator ',')
from table
group by a_id;
```

Comment: That's it.  Thank you.     :)